# Create a combined list from two tables

Tags: sql

I have a table with CostCenter_ID (int) and a second table with Process_ID (int).

I'd like to combine the results of both tables so that each cost center ID is assigned to all process IDs, like so:

```
|CostCenterID | ProcessID |
---------------------------
|      1      |     1     |
|      1      |     2     |
|      1      |     3     |
|      2      |     1     |
|      2      |     2     |
|      2      |     3     |
|      3      |     1     |
|      3      |     2     |
|      3      |     3     |
```

I've done it before but I'm drawing a blank.  I've tried this:

```
SELECT CostCenter_ID,NULL FROM dbo.Cost_Centers
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,Process_ID FROM dbo.Processes
```

which returns this:

```
|CostCenterID | ProcessID |
---------------------------
|      1      |     NULL  |
|      NULL   |     1     |
|      NULL   |     2     |
|      NULL   |     3     |
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
select a.CostCenterID, b.ProcessID 
from table1 a
cross join table2 b
```

or:

```
select a.CostCenterID, b.ProcessID 
from table1 a
,table2 b
```

NB: `cross join` is the better method as it makes it clearer to the reader what your intentions are.

---

More info (with pics) here: http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php

[image: illustration of cross join]